# Laravel queue::after function is not working?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I want to add some additional functionality when the queue is finished. I am using the `queue::after` function in the `AppServiceProvider` but this function is not being triggered. I have tried many solutions which were provided in the same kind of questions on StackOverflow like restarting the queue worker, clearing the cache and `composer dump-autoload` but didn't get any help.

```
 public function boot()
    {
        Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
            \Log::debug("Queue after"); // it should be printed in the logger
        });
    }
```

Any idea where am I going wrong?

Comment: Double-check your logging level. I was able to get this working with `Log::info` instead of `Log::debug` since my logging level is `info`.

Comment: Tried with `\Log::info("Queue after");` still not working

Comment: What is your current logging channel/settings?

Comment: laravel telescope and daily logger files